# QueryBuilder: Search a value in a column containing comma-separated integers

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a column `tags` containing ids in a comma separated list.
I want to search all rows where a given value is in that column.

Say I have two rows where the column `tags` looks like this:

```
Row1: 1,2,3,4
Row2: 2,5,3,12
```

and I want to search for a row where the column contains a `1`. I try to do it this way:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
      ->where(':value IN (p.tags))
      ->setParameter('value', 1);
```

I expect it to do something like

`SELECT p.* FROM mytable AS p WHERE 1 IN (p.tags)`

Executing this in MySQL directly works perfectly. In Doctrine it does not work:

```
Error: Expected Literal, got 'p'
```

It works the other way around, though, but this is not what I need:

`->where("p.tags IN :value")`

I've tried a lot to make this work, but it just won't... Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the definition for the `tags` column?

Comment: Within symfony it's defined as `@ORM\Column(type="simple_array")`, in the database it's a `longtext` field, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation. It contains only integers, separated by commans. Nothing special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use the **LIKE** function for each scenario, as example:

```
        $q = "1";

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->andWhere(
            $this->expr()->orX(
                $this->expr()->like('p.tags', $this->expr()->literal($q.',%')),  // Start with...
                $this->expr()->like('p.tags', $this->expr()->literal('%,'.$q.',%')), // In the middle...
                $this->expr()->like('p.tags', $this->expr()->literal('%,'.$q)),  // End with...
                ),
        );
```

See the SQL statement result [in this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mFXFJqCt8ciZ1n2Raq8ACu/0)

Hope this help

Comment: Wouldn't this also match a `11` or `21` or `132`, when searching for a `1`? I only want it to return a 1. I guess it could be done with regex, but I don't think that this would be an optimal approach performance-wise.

Comment: Hi @krom see my update about the test of the SQL query: please fix the expression about the equal of the single value.

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant approach, but it does work, thank you! :)
FWIW: I'm now using a [ManyToMany](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html) mapping to save the relations to the tags table.